# Unable to change my second monitor's resolution on Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gnome

I've been trying to change my monitor's resolution in settings and each time, I get a black screen and nothing else on my second monitor. I opened gnome-control-center in terminal and tried it and got this error:

`(gnome-control-center:4118): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 00:54:45.379: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: The requested configuration is based on stale information`

I tried restarting, reinstalling, unplugging and plugging it back in and still nothing.

I looked it up online and couldn't fine anyone else that looked like they had the same result on the same OS as me. (I use Zorin OS 15 and it uses Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS as a base.)

Is there something that I can do or do I need to reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to configure the monitors using arandr or xrandr I have found these to be more reliable then the applications provided by most desktop environments.

In addition `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` should contain useful information about what happens when you update the monitor configuration and it might indicate why you are experiencing problems.